# Blogging software using Bootstrap on .NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Are there any open source blogging software projects that uses Twitter Bootstrap for the core CSS styles?

I've used BlogEngine.NET for years, but would like to have a more modern UI look to my blog with easier customizations using a style framework like Bootstrap instead of the totally custom styling that BlogEngine.NET uses.

Preferably I'd like to have something more modern using ASP.NET MVC instead of WebForms.

I'm thinking of starting a new project, but....

Comment: BlogEngine.NET is an exceptionally well written blog application. It shouldn't take much effort to implement twitter bootstrap with it, and I can confirm there are no alternatives that are even closely on par with it. Just because it uses web forms, doesn't mean it isn't MVC'ish in coding style and efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/)? It's a great .NET CMS, written in ASP.NET MVC 4. The development is active and the community is growing.

It's also very pleasant to work with as far as theming goes. I authored a basic blog theme based on Bootstrap myself which you can download for free in the [Orchard Gallery](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Themes/Orchard.Theme.WiseWords).

There is also a plain [Bootstrap Theme](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Themes/Orchard.Theme.Bootstrap), which got updated just 12 days ago.

I have never worked with BlogEngine.NET, but having worked with SharePoint for quite a while, I try to avoid WebForms at all cost.

Answer (score 2):

Although it seems like you may be looking for an open source blogging platform, [Communifire](http://axerosolutions.com/product/features) is a commercial product that utilizes the bootstrap framework.  It contains a complete blogging platform with many additional community and social features like discussion forums, event management, activity streams, chat/messaging, etc.  One of the reasons our customers choose to go with Communifire is the added support and customization options that our company provides.

[Communifire Tech Specs](http://axerosolutions.com/product/technology)

Note that I am an owner at this company.

Comment: Hi, Tim, please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16734) and related Meta discussions on how to proceed when you're promoting your company, thanks!